# How to compare the means of two populations that were subject to five treatments?

Tags: mean, application

I have two populations that were each subject to 5 different treatments and I want to compare their means.

This sounds like a great problem for multiple confidence intervals, but I don't want to make a type 1 error. I also thought about a general linear approach, but I am not sure which one to use. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: As a small hint, search the web for propensity score matching. That might will help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about type 1 errors, keep in mind that you can correct the confidence intervals for multiple comparison (e.g., you can use Bonferroni correction, which is the simplest to apply and more conservative).

If you decide to use a linear model, the best model depends on the structure of your data. The effect of each treatment was measured on the same or on different dependent variables? If there is one common dependent variable, you should probably go for [mixed-effects models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model). There are many tools out there to fit such models, if you are familiar with R, I would definitely recommend the `lme4` library (check [this page](http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org)).